# app crashes while sending intents to a mailing app

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Whenever my app tries to send intents to mailing any mailing app, it crashes.
Can someone please help me to resolve this issue?

Here is my xml code for the intents:

```
Intent intent =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "jainharshil670@yahoo.in");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Coffee Order");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, priceMessage);
    startActivity(intent);
```

The error messages that the app gives in the log file are:

```
07-07 17:48:25.504 22490-22490/com.example.android.justjava E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.example.android.justjava, PID: 22490
                                                                          java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848)
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20262)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5649)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848) 
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20262) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5649) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
                                                                           Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SENDTO typ=*/* (has extras) }
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1792)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3810)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3761)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:871)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4091)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4059)
                                                                              at com.example.android.justjava.MainActivity.submitOrder(MainActivity.java:65)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848) 
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20262) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5649) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Comment: post your xml file and onClick method too

Comment: did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setType()` wipes out the value you put in `setData()`. Instead, combine:

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "jainharshil670@yahoo.in");
```

into:

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("mailto:jainharshil670@yahoo.in"), "text/plain");
```

(replacing `text/plain` with the actual MIME type of the content that you have in `priceMessage`)

Answer (score 0):

Add Activity to your manifest this way:

```
  <activity   android:name=".AppPreferenceActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">  
     <intent-filter> 
       <action android:name="com.scytec.datamobile.vd.gui.android.AppPreferenceActivity" />  
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  
     </intent-filter>   
  </activity>
```

Comment: Show your complete code.Maybe your onclick event somewhere is not going right.

Comment: @Drv What you want ??

Answer (score 0):

It means that the android system doesnt found any email sending activity to handle the intent created by you. Make sure you have email application installed in your device.

Also use the following code to send email,

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("message/rfc822");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"jainharshil670@yahoo.in"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
try {
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail"));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email applications installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I aslo figured it out just after posting this question.

I found it when i saw the lines

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
intent.setType("*/*");
```

Then i deleted:-

```
intent.setType("*/*");
```

And then everything was fine.